# C# ASP.NET CSS style

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have problem with css styles in aspx.cs file

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table class=\'bordered\' cellpadding=\'5\' color: \'red\' <tr>");
```

`class=\'bordered\'` and  `cellpadding=\'5\'` work but `color: \'red\'` not work, I can't find problem please help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`color` needs to be wrapped inside the `style` tag:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table class=\'bordered\' cellpadding=\'5\' style=\"color:red;\"><tr>");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ofapud

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to escape `'` characters since you are using double-quotes.

Try this: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table class='bordered' cellpadding='5' color: 'red' <tr>");`

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple

```
Response.Write("<table class='bordered' cellpadding='5' color: 'red'> <tr>");
```